# How to replace text from a match (but not every match)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, sed, macos

I want to replace `AllowOverride None` from the group that has `/var/www/` path. I'm using sed to do this but it's replacing every match.

**apache2.conf** before running the script

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**apache2.conf** after running the script

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sed "s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g" apache2.conf
```

**My question is:** How can I tell sed to replace where it is `/var/www/`?

Comment: Sure, because sed is reading the file line by line. One way to solve this problem would be a multiline regular expression, another is to split file by <directrory></directory> chunks and apply your logic.

Comment: I would like to see some code, my regex skills are bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following Perl oneliner:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(<Directory\s/var/www/.*?AllowOverride\s)None(.*?</Directory>)}{$1All$2}gs' /tmp/file
```

Here `-0777` flag changes the line separator to undef, so perl will read the file as one line (this might be a problem for big files).

`-p` to loop over lines of file and print them,
`-e` to run the script,
`/tmp/file` your config file

`s{(<Directory\s/var/www/.*?AllowOverride\s)None(.*?</Directory>)}{$1All$2}gs` is the regular expression matching 2 parts of directory stanza with /var/www and basically substituting None to All. Note that in Perl you can use alsmot any symbol as regexp separator, in this case I used `{}` instead of `//`.

Comment: It's printing the updated code, but I want to save it back to the file. MacOS BigSur 11.2.1

Comment: use `-i` flag for that

Answer (score 2):

One way with `sed` is:

```
sed -E '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/{
       s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/; }' infile
```

this updates/changes the *`AllowOverride None`* to *`AllowOverride All`* only if that is between *`<Directory /var/www/>`* & *`</Directory>`* (we escaped slashes with back-slash, it's because slash is special character to the sed command).